# Relatively Positioned Elements and Absolutely Positioned Elements

Tags: html, css

Relatively positioned elements and absolutely positioned elements work hand in hand, right?

An absolutely positioned element is relative to the closest parent element that is relatively positioned, and if there is no relatively positioned element, by default, the absolutely positioned element is relative to the browser viewport, right?

If this is true, if the closest relatively positioned parent elements are above and below the parent of the absolutely positioned element which one would the absolutely positioned element be relative to?

Comment: Can you add any example to explain in brief?

Comment: could you please provide code snippet to understand the scenario well?

Comment: As well as echoing the request for a code snippet to clarify your question, your assertions are not quite accurate. The absolutely positioned element is relative to its nearest non-statically positioned ancestor. That's not necessarily a relatively positioned ancestor - it could be an absolute, fixed or sticky ancestor. Also in the absence of such an ancestor, the absolutely positioned element is relative to the initial containing block, not the viewport.

Comment: @Prashant I don't know how to post HTML and CSS on this website sorry. I've already answered my question though. Thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: @John_ny I need to learn how to post HTML and CSS on this website so I cant post an example right now. I've already answered my question though. Thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: @Alohci you are right alohci. i know this now. I've already answered my question. thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

"Elements that are relatively positioned remain in the normal flow of the document. In contrast, an element that is absolutely positioned is taken out of the flow; thus, other elements are positioned as if it did not exist. The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to its nearest positioned ancestor (i.e., the nearest ancestor that is not static). If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, it is positioned relative to the ICB (initial containing block), which the containing block of the document's root element." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0):

A parent element is per definition always above. There is only one closest parent for each element: `<parent><child/><child/></parent>`.

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background-color: #00BCD4;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
}

section {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
  min-height: 200px;
  flex: 1 0 200px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px 0px #ccc;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin: 3rem;
}

section > div {
  background-color: #E91E63;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

h3 {
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 1rem 3rem 1.5rem 1rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}

.tr {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.br {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.bl {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<main class="relative">

  <h3 class="absolute br">Child of main</h3>

  <section class="relative">
    <div class="absolute"> </div>
    <div class="absolute tr"> </div>
    <div class="absolute br"> </div>
    <div class="absolute bl"> </div>
  </section>

  <section class="relative">
    <div class="absolute"></div>
    <div class="absolute tr"> </div>
    <div class="absolute br"> </div>
    <div class="absolute bl"> </div>
  </section>

</main>
```